# Updating component after componentDidUpdate completes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `react-autosuggest` component which takes a `loading` state prop, as well as a `data` prop from an API request. The `loading` state changes when the `data` prop is hydrated.

In the `react-autosuggest` component, I am trying to use `componentDidUpdate` to automatically render autosuggest results based on the current input (if there is any at the time the props update). In other words, if the user has input a value before the `loading` prop changes (along with the `data` prop), I want the autosuggest results to render automatically when the props change. Currently, the results don't render until the next keystroke is made, based on the `onChange` method built in to `react-autosuggest`.

My parent component:

```
const Home = (props) => {
    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_DATA);

    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

    return (
        <HomeContainer>
            <Logo />
            <Search
                data={data ? data : null}
                home={true}
                loading={loading ? true : false}
            />
        </HomeContainer>
    );
};
```

Some relevant parts of `Search.js`:

```
class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            value: "",
            suggestions: [],
        };
        this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    }
    
    // Only try to render suggestions if loading has finished.
    getSuggestions = (value) => {
        if (!this.props.loading) {
            const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
            const inputLength = inputValue.length;
            const trie = createTrie(this.props.data, "name");
            return inputLength === 0 ? [] : trie.getMatches(inputValue);
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    };

    // I assume this is the method that is currently successfully triggering re-render
    // on input change.
    onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
        this.setState({
            value: newValue,
        });
    };

    // If the data prop has changed and data has hydrated, set the current input value
    // to the this.value state. I need the re-render to happen after this completes,
    // and the value has been set to state. The check against the previous props prevents
    // an infinite updating loop.
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (
            this.props.data !== prevProps.data &&
            Object.keys(this.props.data).length
        ) {
            this.setState({
                value: this.inputRef.current.input.value,
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { value, suggestions } = this.state;

        const inputProps = {
            value,
            onChange: this.onChange,
        };

        return (
                <Autosuggest
                    ref={this.inputRef}
                />
        );
    }
}
```

So everything works fine, other than the fact that I need the component to re-render after the `componentDidUpdate` life cycle completes. It's setting the current input value to state when the loading finishes, but it still requires the keystroke from `onChange` to cause the component to re-render.

How would I go about doing this?

edit: Why isn't the setState in the componentDidUpdate triggering a re-render with the new value? That's all onChange is doing isn't it? Unless the event argument is doing something that I'm missing.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what the issue is. Are you saying `Search` mounts, loads some data and `componentDidUpdate` is called and updates state again, you are now waiting for input, and you don't think the component rerendered when state was updated?  Is this the complete code? I don't see anything invoking `getSuggestions`.

Comment: It's not the complete code, I've removed what I thought was unnecessary code, the full autosuggest usage can be found at: https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest. I removed a lot for simplicity. Everything works fine, I just want any value that is input before the componentDidUpdate to render suggestions as soon as the props and therefore, the state, change. Rather than having to make another keystroke after the props and state change.